# Python3 cffi: is there a way to merge two independent ffi's into one?

Tags: python-3.x, cffi

Suppose I have two libraries which need to work together.  One library has a function that accepts a type built in another library.

Suppose further that I've created two independent FFI interfaces for each of the two libraries.

Now, I have everything working fine for each individual library, but when I go to pass the object type built in one ffi to the other ffi, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'Foo *' appears indeed to be 'Foo *', but the types are different (check that you are not e.g. mixing up different ffi instances)
```

---

What I am trying to avoid is integrating the two libraries into one header and one totally integrated class.  This is because the class will be a one-off and the mix of methods will be random, detailed, specific, over specialized: i.e., hard to name and remember to use later.

Is there some way that I can merge two ffi's so that they can work together?

Or, for example, perform some sort of casting operation from one `ffi's` type to the other? The library backend will work just fine...

(I've tried casting via `second_ffi.cast('Foo *',first_ffi_foo)`, but something more manual seems to be required, like copying the bytes out of the first ffi into the second ffi w/ the cast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by separating the scope of the `cffi.FFI` instance from the classes I am partitioning C-headers into.

By accepting a `cffi.FFI()` option at class declaration, I was able to mix library interfaces together:

```
class LibFoo:
    def __init__(self, ffi_option: Optional[FFI], ...):
       if ffi_option is None:
          self.ffi = FFI()
          self.__ownFFI = True
       else:
          self.ffi = ffi
          self.__ownFFI = False

    def __del__(self):
        if self.__ownFFI:
           # close down the ffi
```

And the composition:

```
class ManyLibs(LibFoo, LibBar):
   def __init__(self):
       self.ffi = FFI()
       LibFoo.__init__(self,self.ffi)
       LibBar.__init__(self.self.ffi)
```